# How to set sublist value using client script in 2.0 Netsuite SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite

How to set sublist value when using in client script. I tried all the method but it's not working and returning the same error.

```
fieldChanged: function(context){
     
     var record = currentRecord.get();
     
     //var record = context.currentRecord; // not working
    
         
     if(context.fieldId =='custpage_cancel'){
         
         var objSublist = record.getSublist({  //returns sublist obj but can not set 
         sublistId: 'custpage_sublist'
         });
        
    
        objSublist.setSublistValue({  // Not working ERROR: objSublist.setSublistValue is not a function
            fieldId : 'custpage_id',
            line : 0,
            value : true
        });
        
        // record.setSublistValue({        // Not working ERROR: objSublist.setSublistValue is not a function
         // sublistId: 'custpage_sublist',
         // fieldId: 'custpage_id',
         // line: 0,
         // value: true
        // });
         
     }
 }
```

ERROR: Screenshot

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try selecting the line and set the value , In netsuite for current record they prefer to use  select line and set values

```
var records = context.currentRecord
 var lineNum = records .selectLine({
    sublistId: 'custpage_sublist',
    line: 0
});

    records.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'custpage_sublist',
                        fieldId: 'custpage_id',
                        value: true,
                        ignoreFieldChange: true
                    });
   records.commitLine({
                        sublistId: 'sublistidentire'
                    });
```

Comment: Right, just for clarity, you do not set field values on the `sublist` object but rather on the `record` object in memory.

Comment: It depends on what type of script you are writing

Comment: The explanation for this is the notion of Dynamic vs Static records : depending on the type of record (when you do a Load, you can specify what kind of record you want to use, but with context or currentRecord, you can not chose, you can find out the type by checking the help or by using log : you will see Dynamic or Static) some functions are not available : for example, you can selectLine with dynamic but with static you get the error "is not a function".

Comment: Are you trying to set this in beforeLoad or afterSumbit?

Comment: @nikhilmeth dude we are talking about client script

Answer (score 0):

try to do the same with a custom list sublist "list" and throw me error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw5mR.png)

---

User event Script

```
function beforeLoad(){

  var form = scriptContext.form;

  var sublistaAplicar=form.addSublist({
    id: 'custpage_invoice', 
    type: 'list',
    label: 'Facturas',
    tab: 'custpage_aplicar'
  });

  sublistaAplicar.addField({
    id : 'custpage_type',
    type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
    label : 'Type'
  });
}
```

---

client script.js

```
function validateField(scriptContext) {

  var currentRecord = scriptContext.currentRecord;

  var lineNum = currentRecord.selectLine({
    sublistId: 'custpage_invoice',
    line: 0
  });

  currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'custpage_invoice',
    fieldId: 'custpage_type',
    value: 'test',
    ignoreFieldChange: true
  });
        
  currentRecord.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'custpage_invoice'
  });
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You may need to use the command of inserting new line first before you select the line when you are on the client script.